# Log in to facebook using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, facebook, http-post, httpurlconnection, facebook-login

I'm trying to login to facebook using httpurlconnect. I think i need to get the cookie from [facebook.com/ajax/bz](https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz) and then pass it along with my login attempt but maybe not. The response just takes me back to the login page and I never log in. Can someone help me get this to log in?

I do not want to use the official API.

```
private String getRequestCookie() throws IOException {
    // URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp");
  /*  URLConnection urlConn = null;
    try {
        urlConn = url.openConnection(currentProxy);
        urlConn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    String cookies = "";
    URL myUrl = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz");
    URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
    urlConn.connect();
    String headerName=null;
    for (int i=1; (headerName = urlConn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
        if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
            String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);
            cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
            String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
            String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
            cookies = cookies+cookieName+"="+cookieValue+"; ";
            //cookieNameList.add(cookieValue);
            System.out.println("da cookies:" + cookies);

            return cookies;
        }
    }
    // must have failed yo
    cookies = "failed";
    return cookies;
}
private String performJsonPost() {
    try {
        String cookies = getRequestCookie();
        String query = "email=EMAILNAME%40EMAIL.com&pass=PASSWORD&lsd=AVrVVnf1&default_persistent=0&timezone=&lgnrnd=132329_hCSS&lgnjs=n&locale=tr_TR";
        URL urls = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");

        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)urls.openConnection();
        final byte[] payloadAsBytes = query.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; reg_ext_ref=deleted; Max-Age=0; datr=0aFzVK8Fu0Gl7M8cn_6TSqlZ");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + payloadAsBytes.length);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        final DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        outStream.write(payloadAsBytes);
        //   outStream.write(payloadAsBytes);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

      /*  catch (Exception e2) {
            //inStream = conn.getErrorStream();
        }*/
            final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            //System.out.println(inStream.toString() + "WHAT ARE U SAYING BRO");
            //while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            //response.append(new String(buffer, "UTF-8").substring(0, bytesRead));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                response.append(line);
                //  inStream = conn.getInputStream();
            }
            return response.toString();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    //    System.out.println("Response!:"+response.toString());
      //  return response.toString();
}
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to login to Facebook using any kind of automated tools, and Facebook is actively taking measures against it. If you want to interact with any users, pages or content on Facebook – then use their API.

Comment: but i already said  that i dont want to

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that you want to do it; according to the [Automated Data Collection Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php), it's not allowed. You app/server can be blocked. Don't do this. Instead, just use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) and all documented features.

Comment: That doesn't matter either  nor does it fit my needs or answer this question